# I have a PDF in Landscape which need to be printed on a Zebra label in portrait mode? What should I do?

Tags: ghostscript, landscape-portrait, portrait

I am using `GhostScript` to print my PDF label to Zebra Label printer. But PDF is in Landscape and hence not printed on the label properly. I want to rotate PDF in Portrait using `Ghostscript` and print.

I have tried many options such as `"-dNORANGEPAGESIZE" ,"-c ".setpdfwrite <<//AutoRotatePages /All>> setdistillerparams"","-dEPSCrop -c "<</Orientation 0>> setpagedevice""` but nothing worked. Is there any way to make this work?

```
%GSC% -dPRINTED -q -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=%5 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=%6 -sDEVICE=%2 %PAGE_SIZE% %OUTPUT_FILE% "%~1" -c ".setpdfwrite <<//AutoRotatePages /All>> setdistillerparams"
```

:End

I expect PDF should be rotated to Portrait using `Ghostscript`

Comment: Maybe you can try change the default settings of the Zebra Printer to print sideways

Comment: No, I can't change printer settings as it will be used for printing other formats also.

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear from your question exactly what you are doing. You've supplied a command line where significant entries are left with batch file variable names (eg %5, %6 etc).

You say you are using Ghostscript to 'print my PDF label to Zebra Label printer' and yet the command line doesn't include a zebra printer device, nor the mswinpr2 device. In fact it uses the pdfwrite device. That means Ghostscript is producing a **PDF** file, not printing to a printer.

The first thing I would suggest is that you make an example file available (and post the URL here).

The next thing is to state clearly what command line you are using (and with all the variables filled in with real values!). Then we can see what the problem is, and reproduce it. Otherwise everything is going to be guesswork.

Now, it seems likely that the reference to the Zebra printer is a misnomer, it seems like you are trying to produce a new PDF file which has been rotated. This probably isn't the best idea in the world. If at all possible you should continue to use the original PDF file and change the printing setup so that it works.

However, assuming for some reason that isn't possible, then **if** you egt the parameters correct, Ghostscript can do that.

The first point is that `-dEPSCrop` won't have **any** effect on PDF input, since it crops EPS input.

Next; `<</Orientation 0>> setpagedevice` is, in effect a no-op, the default Orientation is 0 so you;ve changed it to the default. Setting it to 1 **,ight* haev an effect, but I doubt it.

The PostScript fragtment `<<//AutoRotatePages /All>> setdistillerparams` is almost certainly the exact opposite of what you want. This causes Ghostscript to attempt to rotate pages so that the nmajority of pages in the output have the text running horizontally. If you have a landscape PDF the text is almost certainly already horizontal (of course, in the absence of an example I can't tell). So this won't do anything.

You probably want `<<//AutoRotatePages /None>> setdistillerparams` or more simply `-dAutoRotatePages=/None`. That stops the pdfwrite device rotating the pages when you don't expect it to.

Of course, that **still** won't have any effect (unless I'm misreading the batch file fragment) because it comes **after** the input file name. So Ghostscript will process the input file and the switches up to that point, then process the following PostScript introduced by the -c switch and then exit. The AutoRotatePages would affect any input that came after it, not before it.

Comment: Hello, The exact command is :                                                                         
%GSC% -dPRINTED -q -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=%5 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=%6 -sDEVICE=%2 %PAGE_SIZE% %OUTPUT_FILE% "%~1"

Comment: Our Zebra printer is 203 DPI and it always takes printing as per paper 4*6inches.         The percentage variable are getting replaced:                                                                %GSC% -dPRINTED -q -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=288 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=432 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 %PAGE_SIZE% %OUTPUT_FILE% "R:\_carriers\TPN_UK\Certification\Submission001\Labels\NextDay"

Comment: I'm not using pdfwritedevice command .Please let me know if now question is clear or not. Also, what shoudl be the correct position to use AutoRotatePages. Also if there is any other solution that fits best to rotate pages.

Comment: If you are going to use AutoRotatePages, then you need to use it before the input filename. However, that switch **only** affects the pdfwrite device, so you should not use it if you are using the mswinpr2 device. You need to add -dPDFFitPage and -dFIXEDMEDIA to your command line. You can test the result by using the display device instead of the mswinpr2 device, the behaviour is the same for both (but don't set -dNOPAUSE or you won't see anything). You don't need to set the media size (that gets set from the input PDF file) so you can drop whatever is in %PAGE_SIZE%.

Comment: -dPDFFitPage I was using since morning and is working but fixed media doesn't show any difference.

Comment: Possibly the mswinpr2 device is correctly setting the media size by interrogating the Windows printer driver, I haven't checked to see what it does. If -dPDFFitPage works, then you can remove the %PAPER_SIZE% and -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS and -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS switches.